# Does weaker enemies bill affect item leveling?

Tags: disgaea-3

In Disgaea 3, if I pass a weaker enemies bill it will make it easier to get farther into an item when I enter an item world. Will this have any negative impact on leveling the item?

For example, if I want to get my item past level 30, say, but can't because the enemies are too difficult, I could level up my team some more - or I could just pass a weaker enemies bill and be able to get to item level 40.

Would the end level 40 item be any different if I did it with weaker enemies than if I did it with normal (or even strongest) enemies?

Secondarily, how would weaker enemies affect pirate spawns or anything else while leveling the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How items level up are not directly impacted by enemy levels. So turning it to down to normal is a standard way to rush through the item world. The only requirement is getting Rank 39 to 40 items require World of Carnage turned on when you enter the last level of a legendary.